# GetById of an index in Elastic search through NEST client

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have a model as 
UserModel.cs

```
public class UserModel
{
      public string Id{get; set;}
      public string Name{get; set;}
      public string Age{get;set;}
}
```

And I am unable to get the User while Searching with his userID.

```
var clientProvider = new ElasticClientProvider();    
                var response = await clientProvider.Client.IndexAsync(UserModel, i => i
                    .Index("user_index")
                    .Type("user")
                    .Id(userModel.Id)
                );  

                return response.IsValid;
```

When I am creating a record the _id is getting auto-generated through elastic Search but it is stored as `_id` a meta field but not under the `_source`. And I am unable to access `_id` of meta field through NEST client.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve document by id with help of `Get` method. Here is an example:

```
await client.IndexManyAsync(new []
{
    new Document{Id = "1", Name = "name1"}, 
    new Document{Id = "2"}, 
    new Document{Id = "3"}, 
    new Document{Id = "4"}, 
    new Document{Id = "5"}
});

await client.Indices.RefreshAsync();

var getResponse = await client.GetAsync<Document>("1");

System.Console.WriteLine($"Id: {getResponse.Source.Id} Name: {getResponse.Source.Name}");
```

Prints:

```
Id: 1 Name: name1
```

Document class:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: cant i store the id that is generated by elastic search instead of specifying Id implicitly by me?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3350#issuecomment-410618969) for the answer.

Comment: That answer is not loading. It is popping 500 error. Can u please give me another link.